# C++ Dijkstra Алгоритм Дейкстры не работает на основе списка stl

Tags: c++

Pastebin - https://pastebin.com/hKNgL0xR
Программа выводит какой-то бред, будто он не работает, но при этом условия выполняются. Помогите пожалуйста исправить эту проблему, уже час не виду в чем проблема...
КОД

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
const double INF = 9999;
const int COLORS = 3;
using namespace std;
inline double drand(double d, double u) { return d + (static_cast<double>(rand()) / RAND_MAX) * (u - d); }

template <class T1, class T2> class Graph {
    struct edge {
        T2 w;
        T1 u, v;
        edge(T2 w, T1 u, T1 v) : w(w), u(u), v(v) {}
        bool operator<(const edge& a) const { return w < a.w; }
    };

    T1 V;
    vector<edge>* adjacencyList, edges;

public:
    vector<edge>* getAdjacencyList() { return adjacencyList; }

    // A constructor that builds a graph according to the given parameters of the number of
    // vertices, density and range
    Graph(T1 V = 0, T2 density = 0, T2 dnLim = 0, T2 upLim = 0) : V(V), adjacencyList(new vector<edge>[V]) {
        if (dnLim > upLim) swap(dnLim, upLim);
        for (T1 i = 0; i < V; i++)
            for (T1 e = 0; e < V * min(static_cast<T2>(1), max(static_cast<T2>(0), density)); e++)
                addEdge({ static_cast<T1>(drand(dnLim, upLim)), i, static_cast<T1>(rand() % V) });
    }

    // Add an edge in an undirected graph, return true if edge was added succesfully
    bool addEdge(edge e) {
        if (e.u == e.v) return false; // No loops in this graph
        for (const edge& way : adjacencyList[e.u]) if (way.u == e.v) return false; // No dublicates in this graph
        adjacencyList[e.u].push_back(e);
        adjacencyList[e.v].push_back(e);
        edges.push_back(e);
        return true;
    }

    // Print the adjacency list representation of graph
    void printAdjacencyList(vector<edge>* al = nullptr) {
        if (al == nullptr) al = adjacencyList;
        T1 w = static_cast<T1>(4);
        for (T1 v = 0; v < V; v++) {
            cout << "Vertex " << setw(w) << v << ':';
            for (auto& e : al[v])
                cout << " -> " << setw(w) << e.u << ":w=" << fixed << setprecision(3) << e.w;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    // Minimum distance among unvisited vertices
    T1 minDistance(T2* dist, bool* visited) {
        T2 min = INF;
        T1 index = 0;
        for (T1 i = 0; i < V; i++)
            if (!visited[i] && dist[i] < min) min = dist[i], index = i;
        return index;
    }

    // Typical representation of Dijkstra's algorithm (breadth search)
    pair<T2*, T1*> dijkstra(T1 source, bool r = true, bool g = true, bool b = true) {
        T2* dist = new T2[V];
        T1* prev = new T1[V];
        bool* visited = new bool[V];
        for (T1 i = 0; i < V; i++) dist[i] = INF, prev[i] = -1, visited[i] = false;
        dist[source] = 0, prev[source] = source;
        for (T1 i = 0; i < V - 1; i++) {
            T1 nearest = minDistance(dist, visited);
            visited[nearest] = true;
            for (edge adj : adjacencyList[nearest])
                if (!visited[adj.v] && dist[nearest] != INF && dist[nearest] + adj.w < dist[adj.v])
                    prev[adj.v] = nearest, dist[adj.v] = dist[nearest] + adj.w;
        }

        printAdjacencyList(adjacencyList);
        cout << "PREV:";
        for (T1 i = 0; i < V - 1; i++) cout << ' ' << prev[i];
        cout << endl;
        return make_pair(dist, prev);
    }
};

// The function of calculating the arithmetic mean of only positive numbers not equal
// to infinity, taking into account their number in the array
template <class T1, class T2> T2 calcAveragePositiveDistance(pair<T2*, T1*> p, T1 size) {
    if (size == 0) return 0;
    T2 positiveSum = 0;
    T1 positiveCount = size;
    for (T1 i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (p.second[i] >= 0 && p.first[i] < INF) positiveSum += p.first[i];
        else positiveCount--;
    return positiveSum / positiveCount;
}

int main() {
    short V; cout << "Input V: "; cin >> V; if (V < 0) V = abs(V);
    double density; cout << "Input density (from 0 to 1): "; cin >> density;
    double dnLim; cout << "Input dnLim for random: "; cin >> dnLim;
    double upLim; cout << "Input upLim for random: "; cin >> upLim;
    int source; cout << "Input source vertice (from 0 to " << V - 1 << "): "; cin >> source;
    Graph<short, short> graph(V, density, dnLim, upLim);
    pair<short*, short*> dijkstraInfo = graph.dijkstra(source);
    double avgDist = calcAveragePositiveDistance(dijkstraInfo, V);
    // The output of all the necessary information obtained during the operation of Dijkstra's algorithm
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        cout << source << "\t->\t"
        << i << "\tMin dist:\t" << setprecision(5) << dijkstraInfo.first[i]
        << "\tV Prev:\t" << dijkstraInfo.second[i] << endl;
    cout << "AVERAGE MIN POSITIVE DISTANCE: " << setprecision(5) << avgDist << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И больше просидите. Нужен конкретный пример, что он выводит, а что должен выводить. Уберите рандомную генерацию, заведите один граф и тестируйте на нем. Почитайте что-нибудь про юнит-тесты.

Comment: И в алгоритме вы работаете с дробными числами, а в функции `main` создаете граф с целочисленным значением веса ребра `Graph<short, short>`.

Comment: А вообще странностей немерено. Зачем вообще нужен шаблон класса, если вы точно знаете, какие типы передаются в него? Тем более в конструктор вы принимаете  `Graph(T1 , T2 , T2 , T2)` а в нем же в функцию `double drand(double d, double u)` передаете и возвращаете `double`.  Зачем в конструкторе вектор создавать через `new`? Зачем вообще использовать `short` для целых чисел по логике программы? Вот это всё сильно затрудняет чтение кода, не говоря уже об отладке.

Comment: Шаблон нужен был по заданию, до этого я решал с <int, double> и др по этому на шаблонах написать быстрее, чем потом заменять каждый тип для каждого задания)
С генерацией drand - да, но раз этот тип может в любой округлится, то почему бы и нет) Для этого статик каст был там.
А как создавать вектор ещё? Я не знаю других
А шорт потому что в задании два игрока - 1 и 2 - int для этого слишком много
Чтение кода - может да, сложно, все  эти Т1 Т2 сразу непонятны) Но с другой стороны - stl исходный код тоже нечитаемый сразу (почти)
Спасибо, проблема решена - я не так делаю AL и там некоторые баги

Comment: А зачем менять тип? С чем бы вы не работали, эти типы будут приводиться к `int, double`. Любые количества (количество вершин, количество игроков и т.д.) - целые. Частоты, веса ребер и т.д - `double`. Вы же не контейнер пишете, который должен хранить любой тип данных, включая пользовательский. Вектор просто создается - `std::vector<> `. А массив векторов, как в вашем коде `adjacencyList (new vector<edge>[V])` - `vector< vector<edge> > adjacencyList;`